# integrate $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}^\frac{1}{3}}_{0} x^2*\cos(x^3)\sqrt{sin(x^3)}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}^\frac{1}{3}}_{0} x^2*\cos(x^3)\sqrt{sin(x^3)}dx$$

$u=x^3$

$du=3x^2$

$$\frac{1}{3}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos(u)\sqrt{sin(u)}du$$

$v=sin(u)$

$dv=cos(u)$

$$\frac{1}{3}\int^{1}_{0} \sqrt{v}dv=\frac{2}{9}\sin^3x^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$=\frac{2}{9}\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{2}^\frac{1}{3}}^{\frac{3}{2}}=0.15$$

[but the answer is 0.07](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20x%5E2cos%5E3x*sqrt(sin%5E3x)%20from%200%20to%20(pi%2F2)%5E(1%2F3))

Comment: This looks like the kind of problem that was invented to teach various substitutions.

Comment: Sorry all for editing saw a mistake in the last minute, I have finished editing

Comment: @martycohen but if in the end I come back to the original expression, shouldn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget to change limits of the integral when you change variable.
$$\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}^{1/3}}x^2\cos(x^3)\sqrt{\sin(x^3)}dx \neq \frac{1}{3}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}^{1/3}}\cos(u)\sqrt{\sin(u)}du$$ 
but

$$\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}^{1/3}}x^2cos(x^3)\sqrt{sin(x^3)}dx = \frac{1}{3}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}cos(u)\sqrt{sin(u)}du = \frac{1}{3}\int\limits_0^{1}\sqrt{v}dv = \frac{2}{9},$$ 
where $x^3 = u$ and $sin(u) = v$.

P.S. there is a mistake in the link that you have provided $\sin^3(x) \neq \sin(x^3)$, correct answer is [$\frac{2}{9}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20x%5E2cos(x%5E3)*sqrt(sin(x%5E3))%20from%200%20to%20(pi%2F2)%5E(1%2F3)). Also mind that $du = 3x^2dx$, moreover if you want to use original variables you also have to take original limits.